# computer systems using the AMD chipset and RAID how to get the HDD serial number?

Tags: wmi, raid, serial-number

I took the HDD serial number but it did not result in systems using AMD chipset. In the case of computer systems using RAID then how to get HDD serial number?

```
SelectQuery sq = new SelectQuery("SELECT Tag, SerialNumber FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia"); 

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(sq); foreach (var i2 in searcher.Get()) { string Tag = i2["Tag"].ToString();

if (Tag != "\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0") 

continue;

 string serial = i2["SerialNumber"].ToString();
File.WriteAllText("C:\Caditsys\Serial.txt", serial + Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes its easiest to leverage SmartMonTools. I'm assuming you are using software raid. SmartMonTools will usually tell you the serial number of anything plugged into the motherboard.

```
smartctl --scan
smartctl -i $yourdevice
```

If your disks are behind a hardware RAID controller, it gets trickier, but you can still use smartctl with the -d flag specific to your hardware device.

Comment: But I want an independent program rather than avaiable one what the software can call and check copyrights